Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch In google login in keycloak
I am trying to add the Google login to a website with keycloak. I have created the OAuth credentials in Google and added them in Keycloak. I have taken the redirect URL from Keycloak in Google. When I try to log in, I get the following error:
Access blocked: This application's request is invalid:(Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch)
I nead healp whith this
